# BackGroundWorker hanging Crystal Report

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, backgroundworker

I have a Crystal Report which generates from various DataTables from a button on a Form with a TreeView. I wanted to run a BackGroundWorker so I can add a ProgressBar, since the Crystal Report generated takes some time. I've read that in the first place I needed to add a BackGroundWorker to the control and put all the logic code that generates que long-running process on the DoWork event of the BackGroundWorker. I did it like this:

```
//bgwBackThread is the name of the BackGroundWorkerObject
private void bgwBackThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable reporte = preReportDouble(Ot, Oth);
        DataTable hh = reporteHH(Ot, Oth);
        DataTable otNoCosto = otNoCost(Ot, Oth);
        DataTable dethh = detalleHH(Ot, Oth);

        //cryrepo is a Form which holds a CrystalReportViewer
        InformeMaquina cryrepo = new InformeMaquina();
        cryrepo.Informe = reporte;
        cryrepo.Hh = hh;
        cryrepo.SinCosto = otNoCosto;
        cryrepo.DetHh = dethh;
        cryrepo.Show();
    }
```

and after I assigned the method RunWorkerAsync() to the button which generated the Form 
before

```
   private void btnReporte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bgwBackThread.RunWorkerAsync();
        //Below its commented because before of trying BackGroundWorker I just used the code here.
        /*DataTable reporte = preReportDouble(Ot, Oth);
        DataTable hh = reporteHH(Ot, Oth);
        DataTable otNoCosto = otNoCost(Ot, Oth);
        DataTable dethh = detalleHH(Ot, Oth);

        InformeMaquina cryrepo = new InformeMaquina();
        cryrepo.Informe = reporte;
        cryrepo.Hh = hh;
        cryrepo.SinCosto = otNoCosto;
        cryrepo.DetHh = dethh;
        cryrepo.Show();
        */
    }
```

The problem is when I press the report button with the code as above. It loads the Form which holds que Crystal Report, but this Forms hangs (even in Debug). Without using BackGroundWorker it works fine, but with delay. I've read that its maybe because I'm loading the Form from a non-UI Thread, and that I have to unbind from the UI and then rebind. Is that the Problem?? If it were, how can I unbind and then rebind??

Your help is very apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a private class in your form to hold the DataTable information (which I assume is the time consuming part);

```
private class ReportTables {
  public DataTable reporte;
  public DataTable hh;
  public DataTable otNoCosto;
  public DataTable dethh;
}
```

Create the DataTables and update the results in the e.Result property:

```
private void bgwBackThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  ReportTables rt = new ReportTables();
  rt.reporte = preReportDouble(Ot, Oth);
  rt.hh = reporteHH(Ot, Oth);
  rt.otNoCosto = otNoCost(Ot, Oth);
  rt.dethh = detalleHH(Ot, Oth);
  e.Result = rt;
}
```

Then in the Completed event, show the form:

```
void bgwBackThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                                      RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Error != null) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
  } else {
    ReportsTables rt = e.Result as ReportTables;

    //cryrepo is a Form which holds a CrystalReportViewer
    InformeMaquina cryrepo = new InformeMaquina();
    cryrepo.Informe = rt.reporte;
    cryrepo.Hh = rt.hh;
    cryrepo.SinCosto = rt.otNoCosto;
    cryrepo.DetHh = rt.dethh;
    cryrepo.Show();
  }
}
```

Comment: This gives an InvalidOperationException citing that the control was accessed from a process that is different from the one that created it.